# Saving txt file getting name from inpu ( on a panel)

Tags: java, jpanel

i have 2 void one save a txt with some data and one load that txt and update the game, but anytime i save it, it override the txt file,i would like to save different txt reading the name txt from input this is a button the call the void save, where do i take the input? from the panel adn not from console
`

```
   JButton b=new JButton("Salva");
      add(b);

      b.addActionListener(e -> {
        try {
            Salva();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    });`




       public  void Salva () throws IOException  {
     timer.stop();
     final JTextField xField = new JTextField(10);   // here am i trying to  
     xField.getText();                                // create a text field and put 
                                                       //the strin information
     xField.add(getName(), null);                     //to name the file
        File f=new File("Namefromtxtfield.txt");         //here the name of 
                                                         //        txtfield

         f.createNewFile();             
         PrintWriter c = new PrintWriter(f);
        c.print(crash+" ");

        c.print(collectedcoin+" ");
        c.print(car.getX()+" ");
        c.print(car.getY()+" ");
```

Comment: You want to add text to your file without deleting the actual text? Be more specific what you want to resolve. If its related to your Salva() method, you need to post the code of its method. You are not providing enough information with the code you posted!

Answer (score 0):

Add JTextField and fetch text that is written there, also you can create whole new JPanel with JTextField to open on button click and pass value from there.